# How to observe the end of the series?

Tags: python, series

The problem is that, I don't know how to observe the end of the series.
What i mean:

```
variable = 1
variable = 2
variable = 3
(...)
variable = 14
```

This "variable" grows to a random number (for example: 14) and then suddenly drops to 0

```
variable = 0
```

The biggest problem is that I don't know at what number the "drop" will occur.
How to detect this kind of behavior? (I want to save the number where it occurred, in this case it is "14") Has anyone ever had a similar problem to solve?

Sample code:

```
series = 0
i=1
while i==1:
   variable = 1 (web scraped data e.g "1")
   if variable ==1:
      series = series + 1
   else:
      series = 0
```

Comment: hi, perhaps retain the last number seen while you're looping, and then return that when the value decreases...

Comment: How do you update the variable's value?

Comment: this is web scrap script, the variable is increase when event occur on website. Everything works in infinite "while" loop

Comment: I can't understand the question. Is the first block supposed to be actual code - i.e., do you actually assign to the variable repeatedly? What do you mean by "sudden"? What *actually causes the value to change*? And what do you mean by "detect"? What qualifies as a "drop", and **what should happen** when a "drop" occurs? Please read [ask] and note that we cannot design the program for you, or decide what the program should do; we can only help you write code.

Comment: Sorry for that, the problem seemed simple to understand, I updated the question. I have added a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways:

1 - You can create a global variable to store the max value of variable in each iteration

```
max_value = None
while <condition>:
  if variable > max_value: max_value = variable 
  ....
```

2 - Using List, and get a max of the list. This way you can store all occurrences of the variable

```
valueList = []
while <condition>:
  valueList.append(variable)
  ....
max_vale=max(valueList) #after the while loop
```